# Why marginBottom behaves different in img and span tags? (while both have "display: inline"?)

Tags: css

Why marginBottom behaves different in img and span tags? (while both have "display: inline"?)

Here is a sample:

```
<div>
  <!--margin working for img tag-->
  <img  style='margin-bottom: 50px;' class='img'
     src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1463453091185-61582044d556?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&h=200&q=80' />
  <!--margin not working here???-->
  <span style='margin-bottom: 100px;'>i'm span</span>
</div>
```

codepen: [codepen](https://codepen.io/ya3ya6/pen/MWgBOJK?editors=1100)

Comment: *while both have "display: inline* --> image is inline-block, not inline

Comment: @TemaniAfif i checked it in chrome `computed` section. https://pasteboard.co/IxxqkMg.png

Comment: @TemaniAfif any idea why chrome displays it wrong?

Comment: well, it's not wrong .. technically they are *inline replaced element* and they behave almost the same as *inline-block* but aren't really inline block. My comment wasn't really accurate. Check the duplicate for more details

Comment: @TemaniAfif i get it. there is also more info in the links you provided as duplicate. thanks.

Comment: from the spec : https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#inlineblock-replaced-width / https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#inline-replaced-height .. you will see that they follow the same rule as inline-block replaced element when dealing with margin/height/width